# Is there a way to open file (vs download) file using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page which have following code (which triggers a download of a file at this url)

```
document.location = url;
```

Is there a way to prompt a user to open a downloaded file?

I saw multiple websites showing an arrow pointing at the bottom bar and asking to click on the file.  I am wondered whether there is a better way (as example prompt a user, so the user just have to click "Ok").

My assumption is that it's not possible to prevent execution of different malware. However, I wanted to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. There's no way for your website to override the file open prompt, or the browser's download bar. Like you said, this is for security reasons.

Your best bet is including some images or an explaination that show the user what to do before starting the download.